# Does Clicking Notification bar create a new activity?

Tags: android

The following is my code that configures notification bar.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getApplicationContext(), 
    0,
    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AudioActivity.class),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_star)
     .setContentTitle("My app")
     .setContentText("works")
     .setContentIntent(pi);
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
    Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
);  
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

At runtime, I first show AudioActivity at front-ground, then I open the notification bar that shows a message like "My app works". Clicking on the message opens AudioActivity again.

But it seems that the system calls the onCreate method of AudioActivity when I click notification bar. And before that it does not call the onDestroy of the existing AudioActivity. I was wondering if I have two AudioActivity instances running, and how I can manage them. What I expected is it should have worked as how activities are switched and onStart is used rather onCreate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for you is to make it call onNewIntent and reuse the existing activity

In the called activity:

```
   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       if ("action.action.myactionstring".equals(intent.getAction())) {
           finish();
       }
   }
```

In the called activities mainfest entry

```
   <activity android:name=".MyNotifiedActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="action.action.myactionstring" />
            ...
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

When creating the pending intent

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent("action string");
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getApplicationContext(), 
    0,
    myIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
  );
```

The Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag tells android to reuse the existing instance of the activity (if it exists). onNewIntent is called instead of onCreate, if it isnt already running, the it calls onCreate as usual

Comment: In my code, I replaced new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AudioActivity.class) by new Intent("action string") and added that intent-filter, then it works and it does not call onCreate again. But I also found it does not call onNewIntent.

Comment: What does intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) work for here?

Comment: The "action string" has to match some intent filter you've registered in the manifest (or in code), have you set it up correctly? If you want to post the bits you've changes that match my example I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

@Nick Cardoso: Here is the changed code. I think it works in the way that it does not call onCreate. I was only wondering why it does not call onNewIntent as you expected. Thanks.

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        getApplicationContext(), 
        0,
        new Intent("com.example.myapp.ACTION_NOTIFICATION"),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_star)
         .setContentTitle("My app")
         .setContentText("works")
         .setContentIntent(pi);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
    );
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ourradio.AudioActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_audio"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.ourradio.FeedActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ourradio.FeedActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
        <action 
      android:name="com.example.myapp.ACTION_NOTIFICATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
      android:name="com.example.ourradio.AudioService"
      android:label="@string/label_service_audio" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Because you also need to add category default to the intent filter in the manifest.PLease mark my previous answer as accepted seeing as it has helped you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Joe C , a simpler solution maybe add the SINGLE_TOP flag in the androidManifest as a launchMode in the activity like this:

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.example.ourradio.AudioActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_audio"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.ourradio.FeedActivity" 
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

you can see this link for more information: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode